# QMl ListView elements to C++

Tags: qt, listview, checkbox, qml, qlistwidget

How can I select a few elements in the QML ListView and send the list of selected ListItemText to QListWidget in C++?

I'm using 'contact model' as the model for ListView. The component has a ListItem. The ListItem has a Image(contact avatar), a ListItemText(name of the contact) and a CheckBox. The MouseArea fills the ListItem. Onclicking the ListItem, I can check or uncheck the CheckBox.

Also, I have one more problem. After checking a few elements, if the ListView has a movement (i.e, When I scroll up or down), then all the selected elements are unchecked automatically.

Edited:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::createList()
{
QContactManager *contactManager = new QContactManager("symbian");    
QList<QContactLocalId> contactIds = contactManager->contactIds();
QContact currContact;
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
QImage m_thumbnail;

foreach (const QContactLocalId& id, contactIds)
{
    currContact = contactManager->contact(id);
    if(currContact.type() == QContactType::TypeContact)
    {
        QContactThumbnail avatar(currContact.detail(QContactThumbnail::DefinitionName));
        m_thumbnail = avatar.thumbnail();

        QStandardItem *items = new QStandardItem();
        //items->setData(currContact.displayLabel(), Qt::DisplayRole);
        //items->setData(QPixmap::fromImage(m_thumbnail), Qt::DecorationRole);
        items->setText(currContact.displayLabel());

        if(m_thumbnail.isNull())
        {
            items->setIcon(contactIcon);
        }
        else
        {
            items->setIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(m_thumbnail));
        }
        model->appendRow(items);
    }
}
}

void MainWindow::viewQml()
{
        QDeclarativeView *qmlView = new QDeclarativeView;
        qmlView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/contacts.qml"));
        qmlView->rootContext()->setContextProperty("stdModel", model);
        qmlView->show();
}
```

**contacts.qml**

```
ListView {
id: listView
anchors.top: statusBar.bottom
anchors.right: parent.right
anchors.left: parent.left
anchors.bottom: toolBar.top
clip: true
model: stdModel
//delegate: contactListDelegate
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to show us some of your code

Comment: Also, if you have two questions that are unrelated it would be better to post two questions on stackoverflow instead of combining them.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please put up some code so that we can have a better idea of what you are trying to achieve and what you have already tried.

In regards to your second problem, when you are scrolling up and down, the selected elements are being unchecked because as the documentation states:

> "Delegates are instantiated as needed and may be destroyed at any time.
>   State should never be stored in a delegate."

Thus, when your delegate gets scrolled out of view, it is likely destroyed, and when it returns into view it is created with the default state of being unchecked.

If you would like to retain a delegate when it is scrolled out of view you can check out caching delegates. You can cache delegates when they are scrolled out of view by increasing the cacheBuffer size of your QML list view. **However, be careful, if you have many items in your list increasing the cacheBuffer is not a good idea. You will run out of memory. A better idea would be to implement your list view and list view model using C++.** If you don't understand what I mean by this, check out the [QAbstractListModel class](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qabstractlistmodel.html).

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your reply. Yes. I have many items in my list. (I'm showing list of contacts). So instead of using Qml ContactModel, I think using C++ is a better idea, as you suggest. But I don't know how. I checked that link. But is there any links to explain these with examples.?

Comment: I pasted my code. So far, I tried this. Is that alright? How can I use this model in my contacts.qml page? Now I go this error. "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: stdModel"

Comment: You are on the right track however you are kind of limited by using the QStandardItem model directly which can only have QStandardItems within it. I would suggest subclassing the QAbstractListModel, building your own list modal, and putting custom list elements in it. [Check out this guy's blog here, where he does exactly this.](http://cdumez.blogspot.ca/2010/11/how-to-use-c-list-model-in-qml.html) He explains how to make a custom list model in C++ and how to bring it over to QML. If you would like to store more data within each item (checked/unchecked) then I would suggest this approach.

Comment: Haven't checked your code but stdModel must be StdModel... QML has some goofy naming conventions, make sure that's a capital, doubt that's the issue though. :P

Comment: **Warning:** Setting the context object or adding new context properties after an object has been created in that context is an expensive operation (essentially forcing all bindings to reevaluate). Thus whenever possible you should complete "setup" of the context before using it to create any objects. Ie. Set the context before setting the source.